# Opening hours - Days and times

Tags: 7, datetime

I have created a content type - Shops in College

I would like to display opening days and times. Something like this:

Monday - 09:00-18:00

Tuesday - 09:00-18:00

Wednesday - 09:00-18:00

Thursday - 09:00-18:00

Friday - 09.00-13:00

Saturday - Closed

Sunday - Closed

Is there any way I can do this by managing the fields? Or how would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for Drupal 7 for this called [Opening Hours](http://drupal.org/project/opening_hours) and for 8.x there is [Office Hours](http://drupal.org/project/office_hours).

Comment: Oh thank you Im using Drupal 7 so I will have a look at it now.